# How to stop iphone screen flash with AVFoundation camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation

I'm working on an app (in xcode in objective-c) that takes photos with AVFoundations captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection and I want to stop the screen flashing (NOT the "flash" light on the outside of the phone) and the shutter sound playing every time I take a picture.

Is this possible?

Comment: No. There is no way to programmatically mute the shutter sound.

Comment: You could try capturing frames from the video stream. They're lower resolution but they don't trigger any sound effects.